# perl rename: Prepending something to a set of file names across subdirectories

Tags: regular-expression, perl, rename

Although `perl`'s `rename` tool has become an invaluable companion for my daily work, there are still some quirks that make work more difficult - especially when files are *not* in current work directory.

Let's suppose there are lots of invoices, and we know that all from customer1 are already assigned to an account. So, to make script processing easier later, we want to prepend `assi_` for "assigned".

For example:

```
/home/user/bizz/invoices $ ls -1 t1/inv*

t1/inv_customer1_20130506.txt
t1/inv_customer1_20130823.txt
t1/inv_customer1_20130930.txt
t1/inv_customer2_20131207.txt
t1/inv_customer2_20131113.txt
```

Now look what will happen:

```
/home/user/bizz/invoices $ rename 's/^/assi_/' t1/inv_customer1*

Can't rename t1/inv_customer1_20130506.txt assi_t1/inv_customer1_20130506.txt: No such file or directory
(etc.)
```

Heheh. `rename`  has chosen the **whole path** for prepending `assi_` to, instead of only the file. So no wonder it cannot find *inv_customer1_20130506.txt* in the non-existing *directory* "assi_t1".

So how can `rename` be taught to apply the regular expression to the file name only?

Notes:
1. I don't always want to `cd` to the subdirectories.
2. I would refrain from using loops as well as `find`, if possible.

Comment: What you can say if `rename 's/\//\/assi_/' t1/inv_customer1*`

Comment: Or `rename 's/inv/assi_inv/' t1/inv_customer1*`

Comment: Sure, but this test case is in fact __simplified__ and, above all, showcase. The solution I'm looking for should __always__ be able to prepend a prefix to a filename w/ignoring the directory, and not just by quoting "hard" strings as in your second proposal.

Comment: Do it clear for you what you want? ;) `(cd t1 ; rename 's/^/assi_/' inv_customer1*)` is acceptable to you?

Comment: Or `rename 's|([^/]+$)|assi_$1|' t1/inv_customer1*` you'd like more?

Comment: Proposal #3 is totally unacceptable, since I wrote in my OP clearly that I do __not__ want to cd to the subdirectory. (be glad that we cannot vote -1 on comments :). At least it would encourage certain folks to read the OP more thoroughly.) However, thanks for proposal #4, which is good and which could *maybe* do the trick indeed.

Comment: Regarding #3 please take into attention the brackets around expression. So the command execute in the subprocess and after it the $PWD remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rename` works this way because it can move files between directories. Like `mv`, it acts on the whole path, not just on the last component.

If you only want to modify the last component, you can anchor your regexp at `(\A|?<=/)`, and make sure that it doesn't match any `/` and only matches at the last `/`.

```
rename 's~(\A|?<=/)(?=[^/]*)\z~assi_~' t1/inv_customer1*
```

Another approach is to first split the file name.

```
rename 's~(.*/)~~s; my $d = $1; s/\A/assi_/; $_ = "$d$_"' t1/inv_customer1*
```

You can also use the `File::Spec` module. This has the advantage of coping with non-Unix paths.

```
rename 'use File::Spec::Functions; my ($v,$d,$f) = splitpath($_); $f =~ s/\A/assi_/; $_ = catpath($v,$d,$f)' t1/inv_customer1*
```